# Efficiency of "pre-casting" vs casting each time

Tags: java, performance, casting

Sometimes you need to branch based on `instanceof`, and then do some operations on the concrete type.

```
if (obj instanceof IonObject) { 
    Ion.assertRegistered((IonObject) obj);

    writeMark(((IonObject) obj).getIonMark());

    ((IonObject) obj).save(this);
    return;
}
```

In this case, does making local variable of the desired type make the code more efficient, or is it merely a visual improvement?

```
if (obj instanceof IonObject) {
    // cache the casted value
    IonObject iobj = (IonObject) obj;

    Ion.assertRegistered(iobj);

    writeMark(iobj.getIonMark());

    iobj.save(this);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It eases the code readability and maintainability, that's all.

Comment: So casting doesn't cost anything in runtime?

Comment: Have you run a profiler to see? I'd imagine the compiler would probably optimise that away, but I cannot be certain without running some tests.

Comment: Casting is tremendously cheap, and the JIT (Just-In-Time-Compiler) will optimize things like this anyhow. It's all about readability in this case.

Comment: It does cost, but this cost is so cheap that you should not worry about it.

Comment: Why pick the first snippet at all? It's less readable and does redundant casts.

Comment: Okay, thanks for info. @arshajii that's what I had before I thought it might be worth "pre-casting".

Answer (score 3):

Casting has a small cost as it has to check that the type is appropriate (otherwise it doesn't actually alter anything)

However, in this case you can assume the JIT will optimise this check so that it is done once either way you write the code.

If the code is not run enough to be JITed (which is quite likely) the code will be slightly slower, but doesn't matter because it's not called enough.  i.e. the performance difference between JITed and not JITed is *far* greater.